# Get a width of inner elemets and use it to set a width of outer element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code. But it does not work. I need to set total width of all  and then use it for wrapping div. http://jsfiddle.net/8jPcP/

```
<div id="breadcrumb-wrapper">
   <div>
   <a href="">asd</a>
   <a href="">asd</a>
   <a href="">asd</a>
   <a href="">asd</a>
   <a href="">asd</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change ur code to

```
var totalWidth = 0;
$('#breadcrumb-wrapper a').each(function(index, el) {
   totalWidth = totalWidth + $(this).width();
}); 
$('#breadcrumb-wrapper > div').width(totalWidth);
```

Comment: remove var in var totalWidth = totalWidth + $(this).width();

Answer (score 0):

Update your script like this.

```
 var totalWidth = 0;
$('#breadcrumb-wrapper a').each(function() {
    totalWidth = totalWidth + $(this).width();
   /* alert(totalWidth);*/
});
    $('#breadcrumb-wrapper > div').width(totalWidth);
```

Check the Updated jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8jPcP/1/

Answer (score 0):

The working function would be like this:

```
var totalWidth = 0;
$('#breadcrumb-wrapper a').each(function(index, el) {
    var newWidth = totalWidth + $(this).width();
    totalWidth = newWidth;
});

$('#breadcrumb-wrapper > div').width(totalWidth);
```

You are setting the newWidth with var newWidth in the loop and therefore declaring a differnt variable within the scope of the loop.